# Excel Chart Showing Quarterly User Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, charts

I am having difficulty with adding a chart to visualize the following and would greatly appreciate any help here.

Column A: Shows unique users based on the UNIQUE function: =UNIQUE(Table1[Name])

Column B through E: Shows score percentages by quarter

For example:

| Name | 2020 - Q1 | 2020 - Q2 | 2020 - Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hank | 60% | 75% | 50% |
| Bobby | 97% | 95% | 100% |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking. What kind of chart are you trying to create? What have you tried? Where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: Hi mark - I am trying to create a bar chart with the rep name (x-axis) and score percentage (y-axis), where each bar would be reflective of the quarter.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use the spill range created from UNIQUE to make a table. It would be a lot easier to make a Pivot Table or Pivot Chart where the Table1[Name] is in the Axis/Rows and the Sums of the quarters are in the Values.

Comment: Yes, pivot table would be a simpler solution but the % figures mentioned above were quarterly aggregates populated by formulas (nothing complex, just SUMIFS) from a much larger data set. Additionally, my goal is to have this populate dynamically, without end users needing to refresh pivots or interact with the workbook.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Hello, trying to confirm if charts can be made, based on data points from the UNIQUE function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.